# Using ActionBarSherlock and the support library

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to add menus to my app, and for compatibility with older versions of android I decided to try ActionBarSherlock.

My app uses the support v4 library heavily, for example it uses `ViewPager`.

Now, when I added ActionBarSherlock I got the "jar mismatch" error. Fixed that by removing the support library jar from the build path. but then I get "cannot be resolved to a type" for all the things that use the support library. I got it that ABS exports a few classes such as SherlockFragmentsActivity but it doesn't have anything like `SherlockViewPager`.

How can I use the support library, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is other way to fix it, but just copy the v4 support library from ABS to your project (or the other way around) and add it to the build path. It should work and shouldn't get the "jar mismatch" error. This is the way I do it in my projects.

Comment: I tried to add the jar to the build path using the jar from ABS libs folder but still got "jar mismatch". Only when I replaced the jar in my project's libs folder with the one from ABS, which appears to be newer, did it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ABS is already using the android support library. If you are using it as well, make your project and ABS use the same version.

An easy way is to remove the support library from your project and add to the ABS library project.

That way the support library will be provided to your project at the same time as ABS

Comment: well, as I said, when the support library is removed I get "cannot be resolved to a type" which means that my project doesn't use the one provided by ABS. I just don't understand why or how to fix this....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have 2 versions of library.... one from the ABS and Second while you Added support library. Once try to delete android-support-V4.jar from your lib folder and rebuild the project.